# Sort list of objects by date, where objects don't have name

Tags: python, django, list, django-queryset

I'm trying to to join two querysets and sort the final list by dates. The thing that querysets don't have names. So I am not really sure how to do reference them with lambda.

```
ur_dates =list(unavailable_rooms_prices.values('checkin','checkout').distinct().order_by('checkin'))
ar_dates=list(available_rooms_prices.values('checkin','checkout').distinct().order_by('checkin'))

if ur_dates is not None:
    ar_dates.extend(ur_dates)


sorted_list = ar_dates.sort(key=lambda r: r.checkin)
```

It's the way I am trying to do it, but I get error saying that dict object doesn't have attribute 'checkin'.

As I understand, it should be Foo.checkin. but in this case, what is my foo?

I think Monday morning is putting a mist on my mind.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
sorted_list = sorted(ar_dates, key=lambda r: r['checkin'])
#or
ar_dates.sort(key=lambda r: r['checkin']) #sort is inplace
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `.values()`, the resulting queryset contains `dict`s, not model instances. Therefore, you must use `r['checkin']` instead of `r.checkin`:

```
sorted_list = ar_dates.sort(key=lambda r: r['checkin'])
```

For reference, here is the link to the [documentation of `.values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#values)

Comment: Thank you for explanation, I thought that it has to do something with '.values()'